# Why is $z$ considered a random variable in the following formulation of Locally Linear Embedding Problem?

Tags: machine-learning, embeddings, dimensionality-reduction

The following is the derivation of "Locally Linear Embedding Problem" from the book
Machine Learning, 4-th edt, page 152, by E.Alpaydin.

[image]

[image]

Why is $z$ considered a random variable so that $E(z)=0$ and $Cov(z)=I$ are put as constraints?